# How to define if rebuilding of the full text index has finished?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-indexing

Got a requirement to rebuild mssql full-text index.
Problem is - I need to know exactly when job is done. Therefore - just calling:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG fooCatalog
REBUILD WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
```

doesn't work or I'm doing something slightly wrong. :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can determine the status of the fulltext indexing by querying the [indexing properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/fulltextcatalogproperty-transact-sql) like this:

```
SELECT FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY('IndexingCatalog', 'PopulateStatus') AS Status
```

> Populate Status:
>   0 = Idle
>   1 = Full population in progress
>   2 = Paused
>   3 = Throttled
>   4 = Recovering
>   5 = Shutdown
>   6 = Incremental population in progress
>   7 = Building index
>   8 = Disk is full. Paused.
>   9 = Change tracking

But also pay attention to this note in the article:

> The following properties will be removed in a future release of SQL
>   Server: LogSize and PopulateStatus. Avoid using these properties in
>   new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently
>   use any of them.

EDIT: Corrected link to a newer page and added quote from the note

Comment: So - the best option is to call this in while(status!=0)?

Comment: Ehh... will be fine for now. Still better than waiting X seconds and hoping that rebuild will be finished.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if some event could be raised that you could subscribe on, but I don't think there is one to the best of my knowledge...

Answer (score 4):

Since I cannot comment on Magnus' answer yet (lack of reputation), I will add it here.  I found that there is a conflict of information on MSDN according to [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190370%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).  According to the link I am referencing, the PopulateStatus has 10 possible values listed below:

> ```
> 0 = Idle.
>
> 1 = Full population in progress
>
> 2 = Paused
>
> 3 = Throttled
>
> 4 = Recovering
>
> 5 = Shutdown
>
> 6 = Incremental population in progress
>
> 7 = Building index
>
> 8 = Disk is full.  Paused.
>
> 9 = Change tracking
> ```

Comment: This list is perhaps more correct than the one that only goes up to 5. Using SQL2012 I saw a status of 9 immediately after repopulating my Full Text Indexed table.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name, case FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY(name, 'PopulateStatus') 
    when 0 then 'Idle'
    when 1 then ' Full population in progress'
    when 2 then ' Paused'
    when 3 then ' Throttled'
    when 4 then ' Recovering'
    when 5 then ' Shutdown'
    when 6 then ' Incremental population in progress'
    when 7 then ' Building index'
    when 8 then ' Disk is full.  Paused.'
    when 9 then ' Change tracking' end AS Status
from sys.fulltext_catalogs
```