# SQL Server 2005 FTS unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have an Indexed View with two columns, a primary key char and a field for full-text indexing varchar(300). I need to search from a MS Great Plains database, so I created the view to populate a field with concatenated values from my primary table IV00101.

```
CREATE VIEW SearchablePartContent WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
SELECT ITEMNMBR, rtrim(ITEMNMBR)+' '+rtrim(ITMSHNAM)+' '+rtrim(ITMGEDSC)
 as SearchableContent
FROM dbo.IV00101
GO
-- create the index on the view to be used as full text key index
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ITEMNMBR ON SearchablePartContent(ITEMNMBR)
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON SearchablePartContent(SearchableContent) KEY INDEX IDX_ITEMNMBR ON Cat1_PartContent
WHILE fulltextcatalogproperty('Cat1_PartContent','populatestatus') <> 0
BEGIN
 WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
END
```

The problem is that when I do a search with particular keyword(s) it will yield unexpected results. For instance a simple query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM SearchablePartContent WHERE CONTAINS(SearchableContent, 'rotor')
```

should yield 5 results, instead I get 1. There's about 72,000 records indexed. However, if I do a LIKE comparison, I will get the expected rows. My data is not complex, here are a couple results that should be returned from my query, but are not:

1. MN-H151536 John Chopper, Rotor Assembly Monkey 8820,9600,8820FRT
2. MN-H152756 John Rotor, Bearing 9650STS,9750STS1
3. MN-H160613 John Rotor, Bearing 9650STS,9750STS2

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: Try enclosing your search term with double quotes to see if it makes a difference.

```
SELECT * FROM SearchablePartContent WHERE CONTAINS(SearchableContent, ' "rotor" ')
```

Comment: Thank you Joe, unfortunately that isn't the issue; I think the "" are meant for phrasing. As you can see the the three results I listed, there is nothing obscure about that data; those columns just aren't being indexed for some reason.

Comment: I've heard of, but never personally experienced, cases where FTS acts case-sensitive despite what the database collation may be. Does searching 'Rotor' make a difference vs. 'rotor'?

Comment: Joe, not at all. Those 3 records I listed look pretty much the same as the results that do show up. Notice how #1 and #2 are fairly close. The other piece I forgot to mention is that when I narrow down my indexing to say.. 10,000 or 2,000 records, I can perform the same search and yield the correct results.

Comment: For example, if you notice my query for creating my view. To narrow it I will tack on something like:

FROM dbo.IV00101 WHERE ITEMNMBR LIKE 'MN-H15%' ...which will cut that 72,000 indexed view result set to maybe a thousand. Then I'll run my query and I will get the results I need.

It's like FTS is nit-picking what it wants to index ...and I'm not sure on what.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, but it's really starting to sound like your fulltext index is not finished populating. I know PopulateStatus is deprecated for fulltextcatalogproperty. Try testing `OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID(N'SearchablePartContent'), N'TableFulltextPopulateStatus') <> 0` instead and see if that makes any difference.