# Charindex vs Contains delivering very different results

Tags: sql, contains

I am running two queries that are supposed to do the same thing on our CV database table:

1. `CONTAINS` (full-text indexed table - cv, fullname etc are all included in the index)

   ```
    SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM [CVDatabase] 
    WHERE CONTAINS ((CVText, fullname, city, CompanyName, jobTitle, targetJobTitle),'"cost accountant*"') AND (Country='South Africa')
   ```

   Number of results: 300
2. `CHARINDEX` (unindexed)

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(1) 
   FROM [CVDatabase] 
   WHERE (CHARINDEX ('cost accountant', cvtext) > 0 OR 
          CHARINDEX ('cost accountant', fullname) > 0 OR 
          CHARINDEX ('cost accountant', city) > 0 OR
          CHARINDEX ('cost accountant', companyname) > 0 OR
          CHARINDEX ('cost accountant', jobtitle) > 0 OR
          CHARINDEX ('cost accountant', targetjobtitle) > 0) 
     AND (Country = 'South Africa')
   ```

   Number of results: 339

This is over a 10% discrepancy. Naturally `CHARINDEX` with capture 'cost accountant', 'cost accountants' (which `CONTAINS` will also capture with the wildcard). The difference might come from characters before 'cost accountant' which `CHARINDEX` will capture but not `CONTAINS` - but I cannot think of any characters that would make sense before the word 'cost'.

Is it possible there is something wrong with the indexing, and it is not picking up all the results? It is set to track automatic changes so it should be indexing correctly.

Comment: Is this SQL Server? Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are all those rows indexed?
2. SQL FT will split the text into words so it will not find "xyzcost accountant", but that's probably ok. Still, what happens if you search for "cost accountant" (i.e. without the wildcard"?
3. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727911/how-can-i-know-when-sql-full-text-index-population-is-finished) are some details on how to check if the indexing process has completed. Note that if it hasn't your queries still run but produce inconsistent results (i.e less results). This is because the designers of FT want to enable the system to update and insert new data without downtime but a little data loss may happen.
4. The [examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx) on msdn do not show how to combine phrase search with an wildcard. Maybe you could use "NEAR" instead?

Comment: 1) Yes - all these rows are indexed.

Comment: 2) 270 results
3) I get an idle response

Comment: Apologies for the split response - my machine doing strange things! Also - many thanks for the repsonse.