# Why doesn't full text indexing work in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-indexing

I have full text index on `field1` in `table1`. The problem is that not all expected rows are returned when doing a query.

Example:

```
select * 
from CONTAINSTABLE(xxxdb.dbo.table1, field1, '"123 456"' )
```

returns

```
123 456 1.1
123 456 1.2
123 456 1.3
```

but not

```
123 456 1.4
```

If I use

```
select * 
from xxxdb.dbo.table1 where field1 like '%123 456%'
```

then I get all 4 rows

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this behavior or how to troubleshoot? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you post executable code that creates all necessary objects and data?

Comment: Is it possible the [full text index population hasn't completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727911/how-can-i-know-when-sql-full-text-index-population-is-finished)?

Comment: @usr for now i cannot because the data is a confidential. I will try to reproduce with other data and post back if i succeed.

Comment: @DMason I just dont know and dont know how to find out - all queries i found online that are supposed to give me the status return empty tables

Comment: Did the link to the other SO question help?  There's a lot of good info there.