# committed inserted data not immediately available for select involving full text search

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2014

I have 2 stored procedures - simplified/pseudo code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SomeSchema].[Sproc1]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION X;

        -- Insert lots of data

        COMMIT TRANSACTION X;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT  
            @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER() ,
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY() ,
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE() ,
            @ErrorProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE() ,
            @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE() ,
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION X;
     END CATCH; 
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE [SomeSchema].[Sproc2]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION X;

        -- Perform full text search on old and inserted data and return

        COMMIT TRANSACTION X;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT  
            @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER() ,
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY() ,
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE() ,
            @ErrorProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE() ,
            @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE() ,
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION X;
     END CATCH; 
END;
```

The first stored procedure Sproc1 inserts some data into several normalized tables. The second Sproc2 then selects data from the database using full text search. I run both stored procedures as follows:

```
EXEC [SomeSchema].[Sproc1]
EXEC [SomeSchema].[Sproc2]
```

Unfortunately data inserted via Sproc1 is not yet available when Sproc2 is run - only after about 1-3 seconds (guesstimate). What could be the reason for this? Should all this not be synchronous/atomic - i.e. the data should be available/selectable at the time Sproc2 executes?

Any suggestions to enforce that data insert/index is completed before Sproc2 is invoked would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

PS:

Just isolated the problem a sproc that is invoked inside Sproc2. This sproc uses sp_executesql and does not run inside a transaction. Not sure why this causes problems though ...

PPS:

It all seems to be related to full text search. This is part of my SSDT post-deployment script:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [SomeFullTextCatalog]
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
AS DEFAULT;
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ClusteredIndex_SomeView 
    ON [SomeSchema].[SomeView] (SomeId);
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [SomeSchema].[SomeView ](
[Some1] LANGUAGE 'British English', 
[Some2] LANGUAGE 'British English', 
[Some3] LANGUAGE 'British English', 
[Some4] LANGUAGE 'British English')
KEY INDEX [ClusteredIndex_SomeView] ON ([SomeFullTextCatalog], FILEGROUP [PRIMARY])
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = SYSTEM)
```

How can I 'refresh' this after an insert?

I can do:

I understand that I can do:

```
SELECT FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY('SomeFullTextCatalog', 'PopulateStatus') AS Status
```

to check the status of the full text catalog and wait until its value is 0 again. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have any special isolation level turned on?

Comment: nope it is read committed tried dirty read and everything. Just isolated the problem a sproc that is invoked inside Sproc2. This sproc uses sp_executesql and does not run inside a transaction. Not sure why this causes problems though ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the full text index needs some time to refresh. To create a wait for this I have used this sproc taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727911/how-can-i-know-when-sql-full-text-index-population-is-finished):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Core].[USP_Core_WaitForFullTextIndexing]
    @CatalogName VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @status int;
    SET @status = 1;
    DECLARE @waitLoops int;
    SET @waitLoops = 0;

    WHILE @status > 0 AND @waitLoops < 100
    BEGIN       
        SELECT @status = FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY(@CatalogName,'PopulateStatus')
        FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs AS cat;

        IF @status > 0
        BEGIN
            -- prevent thrashing
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.1';
        END
        SET @waitLoops = @waitLoops + 1;
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to recreated the full text index again, actually you need to do it once a day, to get all the inserted data for that day available.

Comment: It seems to work about 2 seconds later though without having to recreate the full text index though. Btw, I do my full text index against a view. How can force this to be refreshed after the insert?