# Fulltext index crawls stuck at has_crawl_completed 0

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, fulltext-index

On a ~100GB database with hundreds of tables I've created fulltext catalogs per-table. I set all the change tracking to OFF just to begin. After over a day, most of the indexes have finished crawling, but there are some which haven't finished. In `sys.fulltext_indexes` the `has_crawl_completed` for these indexes still show `0`.

Referring to the answer from [How can I know when SQL Full Text Index Population is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727911/how-can-i-know-when-sql-full-text-index-population-is-finished/10505496), I check the PopulateStatus of the catalogs corresponding to these not completed indexes. There is one catalog that is in the `Full Population In Progress` status and a few catalogs that are in the `Idle` status.

Is there anything I can do to monitor the catalog which is in `Full Population In Progress`? What does a catalog that's `Idle` but has incomplete crawls mean -- what is the purpose of those indexes if the catalog for them is already `Idle`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retry crawling on the stuck indexes by running this for every index that had a 0 for `has_crawl_completed`:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG <catalog-name> REBUILD;
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON <table-name> START FULL POPULATION;
```

and the retries completed eventually.

Comment: If anyone has a good explanation for what `Idle` status combined with `has_crawl_completed` 0 means, I'd be happy to accept your answer.